# Isolating first command line arg assembly and modding it

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, modulo

I'm currently working with a nasm program in Assembly and I'm trying to write a program to determine if the first command line arg given is a leap year or not. I've successfully processed argument handling and the proper message displays when a user enters anything but one command line arg, but now I'm confused about how to "access" the year provided and mod it with numbers. Here is my code so far

```
        global  main
        extern  puts
        extern printf
        extern atoi


        section  .text

main:
        push    r13
        push    r14
        sub     rsp, 8


        cmp     rdi, 2
        jne     error1              ; jump if aguments != 1
        jmp     done
error1:
        mov     edi, badArgs
        call    puts
        jmp     done  

done:
        pop     r14
        pop     r13
        add     rsp, 8
        ret

badArgs:
       db      "Requires exactly one argument", 5, 0
```

The line in question occurs right after my jne line which checks for bad args. Now I want to isolate the argument (which I believe is located in the rsi register) and mod it with the number 4 to begin my leap year cheks. How do I isolate this value and mod it with 4?

Comment: I gather this isn't Windows, I assume 64-bit Linux? If so _RSI_ will contain a pointer to an array of char * pointers. The first element of that array will be a pointer to the first argument (program name). You'll have to advance to the next pointer (pointers are 8 bytes wide) to get the pointer to the second argument (first parameter after the program name).

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes this is 64-bit Linux. I will give that a try thank you!

Comment: If you hadn't figured it out, here is a hint. you can print the first parameter (program name) by `mov rdi, [rsi]` `call puts` . You could print the second parameter with `mov rdi,[rsi+8]` `call puts`

Comment: "mod it with numbers"?  Smells like the [FAQ: how do I handle multi-digit numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  You need to convert from string to integer and back.  `% 4` only requires checking the low 2 bits of the base 2 representation, but it's not that easy in base10.